# OpenAM, Not found error, then reload works

Tags: active-directory, openam

We are using OpenAM to authenticate with out Active Directory users. We are running into a very odd problem.

We login using the `mail` attribute which belongs to the `user` object class in Active Directory. Upon logging in a **Not found** error appears on the screen. Looking into the network tab we see that there was a request to `openam/json/realms/root/users/<mail@domain.com>`, but it returns a 404.

If we close the tab and reload the login url again, it immediately goes to the consent screen and displays the user's conical name. Accepting the agreement successfully sends us to the specified redirect uri.

Info:

- There a module that looks into a Data Store that is hooked pulls a certain organization group (the data store appears to work fine)
- There is a simple chain that uses that module

Any ideas?

Comment: The REST identity call will ends up in the search method of the user data store configured for the realm (API being implemented https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13.5/apidocs/src-html/com/sun/identity/idm/IdRepo.html#line.365). You need to check the 'LDAP Users Search Attribute' for the configured user data store (https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13.5/admin-guide/index.html#sec-data-stores-active-directory). It must be set to 'mail'. I'm linking OpenAM docs as you mentioned OpenAM and not ForgeRock AccessManagement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to determine the problem after digging into the OpenAM logs.

I turned on **message** level debugging and say that the **Not found** error was not a problem with find the user in AD, but a problem finding groups in AD.

By default the datastore we had created was searching for groups with some arbitrary attributes, but our AD does not have groups. **We set all the group search fields to be blank and this resolved our problem.**